# Deploying ember-cli dist returns an empty page

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've executed the following command to build ember for production environment. However when I opened the dist folder, clicked the index.html it returned a blank page. compared to as when I run ember server.

The command I've used to generate the dist folder

```
ember build --environment production
```

Here's how I do it dist folder -> click the index.html.

Here's the result.

[image]

Here's the contents of the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>TodoMvc</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <base href="/" />
<meta name="todo-mvc/config/environment" content="%7B%22modulePrefix%22%3A%22todo-mvc%22%2C%22environment%22%3A%22development%22%2C%22baseURL%22%3A%22/%22%2C%22locationType%22%3A%22auto%22%2C%22EmberENV%22%3A%7B%22FEATURES%22%3A%7B%7D%7D%2C%22APP%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22todo-mvc%22%2C%22version%22%3A%220.0.0+8f1032d8%22%7D%2C%22contentSecurityPolicyHeader%22%3A%22Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only%22%2C%22contentSecurityPolicy%22%3A%7B%22default-src%22%3A%22%27none%27%22%2C%22script-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%20%27unsafe-eval%27%22%2C%22font-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22connect-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22img-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22style-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%2C%22media-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%22%7D%2C%22exportApplicationGlobal%22%3Atrue%7D" />
<script src="/ember-cli-live-reload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/todo-mvc.css">


  </head>
  <body>


    <script src="assets/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/todo-mvc.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the error message[image]

Comment: What are the contents of index.html? Are there any console messages?

Comment: You don't just double click the index.html file, you need a webserver to serve it otherwise you are accessing it via the file protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing it the wrong way. I deployed the app to an http web server. turns out by clicking the index.html. I'm accessing it via the file protocol